# Kicad CONN_3X8 schematic component?

Tags: schematics, layout, kicad, footprint, header

I am designing a prototype board in `Kicad`. I need `CONN_3X8` schematic component and footprint module for connecting 8 off-board `ESC` to my prototype board. I can't find any such connector in Kicad and also creating it will be messy.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create it. It will not be messy. That's a skill you'll acquire sooner or later, anyway.

Comment: Also, OP, there is a 2x8 pin header footprint. Making a 3x8 footprint will be trivial (assuming you want 100th or 2mm headers?)

Comment: But how can i represent 3 columns of pins at two sides of component in schematics?

Comment: you'd normally don't – you just use a connector with 24 pins. Notice: KiCad makes a distinction between schematic symbol and component footprint (and you should, too, if you use kicad). If you really want: obviously, create a matching schematic symbol.

Comment: "you just use a connector with 24 pins". Thanks. I will use 24 pins connector!

Answer (score 2):

I use snapEDA to find footprint on kicad and eagle. https://www.snapeda.com/
You can also create the footprint on your own, it's a pretty easy one though..